# Recursive crawling with BeautifulSoup really slow

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm building a crawler that downloads all `.pdf` Files of a given website and its subpages. For this, I've used built-in functionalities around the below simplified recursive function that retrieves all links of a given URL.

However this becomes quite slow, the longer it crawls a given website (may take 2 minutes or longer per URL).
I can't quite figure out what's causing this and would really appreciate suggestions on what needs to be changed in order to increase the speed.

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

pages = set()

def get_links(page_url):
  global pages
  pattern = re.compile("^(/)")
  html = requests.get(f"https://www.srs-stahl.de/{page_url}").text
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
  for link in soup.find_all("a", href=pattern):
    if "href" in link.attrs:
      if link.attrs["href"] not in pages:
        new_page = link.attrs["href"]
        print(new_page)
        pages.add(new_page)
        get_links(new_page)
        
get_links("")
```

Comment: you might be stuck on some infinite recursion, not sure it is related to your question but you will have to uniquify your pages list (pages = list(set(pages))
Otherwise if page A takes you to page B and page B takes you to page  A you'll be stuck there forever

Comment: Isn't that the same as what I'm doing with  if link.attrs["href"] not in pages?

Comment: maybe it's just a server problem

Comment: add a time printer, might be the case that the server delays your request more and more.

Answer (score 2):

*It is not that easy to figure out what activly slow down your crawling - It is maybe the way you crawl, server of the website, ...*

In your code, you request a URL, grab the links and call the functions itself in the first iteration, so you only append requested urls.

You may want to work with "queues" to keep the processes more transparent.

One advantage is that if the script aborts, you have this information stored and can access it to start from the urls you already have collected to visit. Quite the opposite of your for loop, which may have to start at an earlier point to ensure it get all urls.

Another point is, you request the PDF files, but without using the response in any way. Wouldn't it make more sense to either download and save them directly or skip the request and at least keep the links in separate "queue" for post processing?

##### Collected information in comparison - Based on iterations

**Code in question:**

```
pages --> 24
```

**Example code (without delay):**

```
urlsVisited --> 24
urlsToVisit --> 87 
urlsToDownload --> 67
```

#### Example

*Just to demonstrate, feel free to create defs, classes and structure to your needs. Note added some delay, but you can skip it if you like. "Queues" to demonstrate the process are lists but should be files, database,... to store your data safely.*

```
import requests, time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
baseUrl = 'https://www.srs-stahl.de'
urlsToDownload = []
urlsToVisit = ["https://www.srs-stahl.de/"]
urlsVisited = []

def crawl(url):
    html = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
    for a in soup.select('a[href^="/"]'):
        url = f"{baseUrl}{a['href']}"
        if '.pdf' in url and url not in urlsToDownload:
            urlsToDownload.append(url)
        else:
            if url not in urlsToVisit and url not in urlsVisited:
                urlsToVisit.append(url)
                
while urlsToVisit:
    url = urlsToVisit.pop(0)
    try:
        crawl(url)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f'Failed to crawl: {url} -> error {e}')
    finally:
        urlsVisited.append(url)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Currently still building around this, what a very helpful answer! thanks a lot.